# DolphinDB: How to set a threshold for cumulative calculation?

Tags: cumulative-sum, dolphindb

I want to create a column “X“ where the values are cumulative sums of an original column “Y“. However, when a value in “X“ reaches a certain threshold (e.g., an absolute value less than 1,000), the cumulative calculation restarts from the next value in “Y“.

For example, given the original column "Y" with values [1100, 1100, -1300, -10000, 1000], how to get the desired result with values [1100, 2200, 900, -10000, -9000]?

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the `cumsum` function to cumulatively calculate the sum of the elements in "Y" and use the `iif` function to set the threshold. Here is an example script:

```
Y = [1100, 1100, -1300, -10000, 1000]
X = cumsum Y;
X - ffill(prev iif(1000>abs X,X,00)).nullFill(0);
```